# rainbow.js randomize from a list on load?

Tags: javascript, random, gradient

I have this rainbow changing the background color of a div:

```js
var numberOfItems = 40;
var rainbow = new Rainbow();
rainbow.setNumberRange(1, numberOfItems);
rainbow.setSpectrum('#e8e2d1', '2b2928');
var s = '';
var colors = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfItems; i++) {
    var hexColour = '#' +rainbow.colourAt(i);
    colors.push(hexColour)

}
```

was wondering if there was a way to make it that the spectrum (in this case '#e8e2d1', '2b2928') is randomized from 2-3 options so that each time the page is loaded the gradient will be different?

Comment: Yes, its possible.

Comment: Yeah, thought so! Do you have a minute to help me understand? I am an absolute rookie and self teaching

Comment: Are the color hex code "start" and "end" of the range, or two examples from inside the range?

Comment: They are the start and end point, the "40" is the number of steps in between that I want the function to generate!
would love to be able to put idk like 
red-yellow
orange-green
blue-white 
and then have the function (where setspectrum is? maybe?) to pick from one of the three?